# Arcmap digitize map display on android offline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-android, arcgis-runtime

Im quite new in arcmap map and i have been spending more than 2 week stuck in how to show map offline. I have tried the code is attached but when i run the application.It crashes nothing to show. You can see my code and i also attached geodatabase file.

i follow this tutorial: http://www.activeg.com/agBlog/android-running-an-arcgis-map-offline

And my geodatabase file is here https://files.fm/u/q5xuznvy

Code is here

```
MapView mMapView;
```

Geodatabase geodatabase;
private GeodatabaseFeatureTable geodatabaseFeatureTable;
private FeatureLayer featureLayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map); //Instantiates the MapView object
LoadMap mLoadMap = new LoadMap(); //Runs the LoadMap class on another thread
mLoadMap.execute(); //Calls the background thread
```

}

private class LoadMap extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try { //Opens up the basemap.geodatabase file from it's location on the physical device
        Log.d("_EXC", "Loading File");
        geodatabase = new Geodatabase("/mnt/shared/Database/mygeodata.gdb");
        Log.d("_EXC", "File Loaded");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("_EXC", e.getMessage());
    } finally { //Takes each layer one by one from the Geodatabase and adds it to the MapView
        if (geodatabase == null){
            Log.d("_EXC", "File not Loaded");
        }
        for (int i = (geodatabase.getGeodatabaseTables().size()) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            geodatabaseFeatureTable = geodatabase.getGeodatabaseFeatureTableByLayerId(i);
            featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(geodatabaseFeatureTable);
            mMapView.addLayer(featureLayer);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: look into http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your data format `mygeodata.gdb` presumably generated with ArcMap.  You need to create a `*.geodatabase` runtime geodatabase file for use with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android.  Looks like you are using version 10.2.x, below are some relevant references:

- Supported [Geodatabase formats](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/guide/supported-geodatabase-formats.htm)
- [Create an Offline Map](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/guide/create-an-offline-map.htm)
- Programmatically [create an offline geodatabase](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/sample-code/create-runtime-geodatabase/)

Comment: I created .geodatabase file instead of .gdb.
This step
 geodatabase = new Geodatabase("/mnt/shared/Database/mygeodata.gdb");
how to do if i want to put .geodatabase file in application instead of device?

Comment: Putting in app is not directly supported.